# Retrieve Object from complex Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array :

```
var hemicycle = {

    Group1 : [{
      GroupName : "Les bests",
        Member1 : [{
            Name : "Loris Plasson",
            Seat : 4,
            Vignette : "PhotoURL"
        }],
        Member2 : [{
          Name : "Anne-Sophie",
          Seat : 3,
          Vignette : "PhotoURL"
      }]

    }]
```

I want to push the object `Member1` or `Member2` on another object depending of the `Seat` value.

To do that I think I need to "search" for the Seat value with a for loop and retrieve the object, but all the examples I found on StackOverflow were with simple arrays like this :

```
var array = [
    { name:"string 1", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", value:"this", other: "that" }
];
```

With those simple arrays they are able to use something like a for loop with `array[i]`.

But in my case I really don't know what to do...

**UPDATE : What I want :** The Member object which include the corresponding Seat value searched. Then I push the Member object to another object.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you expect as end result?

Comment: What is the seat criterion (seat > 3 for example)? Is there only one object with each seat value, or there could be multiple people with `Seat: 3` for example?

Comment: You can do a search using a loop on `hemicycle.Group1`

Comment: The member object which include the corresponding Seat value. @Durga

Comment: @OriDrori the Seat value is unique.

Comment: Why are the member objects inside an array as well?

Comment: @OriDrori There are multiple groups with multiple members on each groups.

Comment: but each member is an array as well, for example `        Member1 : [{
            Name : "Loris Plasson",
            Seat : 4,
            Vignette : "PhotoURL"
        }],`. Why should it be an array?

Comment: I thought this would be the best way to store these values. Is there an other way to store this ?

Comment: This is how your data should look: `hemicycle = [
 {
      GroupName : "Les bests",
   members: [{
            Name : "Loris Plasson",
            Seat : 4,
            Vignette : "PhotoURL"
        },
        {
          Name : "Anne-Sophie",
          Seat : 3,
          Vignette : "PhotoURL"
      }]
 }
]`

Comment: It's an array of groups. Each group is an object, that has the `members` property, which is an array of member objects.

Comment: I replaced with your suggestion, but I am not able to find my object with Seat value. Here is my function : https://paste.ofcode.org/5wnq8ZSnCCTAZqzShXqwEt
When I do `search(3, hemicycle)` I get : undefined

Comment: Nevermind I forgot something on my function. It works now ! Thanks a lot ! Put your solution as an answer so that I can approve it.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've added an answer that includes how to find the member. Your solution won't work if the member is in the 2nd group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure that you use doesn't reflect what you are trying to convey, and in addition is very heard to traverse.

I suggest creating an array of groups. Each group is an object, that has the members property, which is an array of member objects:

```
[{
  "GroupName": "Les bests",
  "members": [{
      "Name": "Loris Plasson",
      "Seat": 4,
      "Vignette": "PhotoURL"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Anne-Sophie",
      "Seat": 3,
      "Vignette": "PhotoURL"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Using this structure, you find a member using 2 for loops - one to iterate the groups, and the other to iterate the members of each group. Once a member is found, the function returns the member's object immediately. If not `undefined` is returned:

```js
var groups = [{"GroupName":"Les bests","members":[{"Name":"Loris Plasson","Seat":4,"Vignette":"PhotoURL"},{"Name":"Anne-Sophie","Seat":3,"Vignette":"PhotoURL"}]}];

var seatNum = 4;

function findMember(seatNum) {
  var members;
  for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    members = groups[i].members;
    for(var j = 0; j < members.length; j++) {
      if(members[j].Seat = seatNum) {
        return members[j];
      }
    }
  }
}

var member = findMember(seatNum);

console.log(member);
```